# API de mercadolibre

Tags: json, api, curl

Tengo un inconveniente al obtener el nuevo id de una [republicación de ítem](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/es/re-publica/) directamente desde **MercadoLibre**.

Si yo republico un ítem obtengo el nuevo *id* y no hay inconveniente, pero si la republicación la hace *MercadoLibre* directamente, no sé cómo obtener ese nuevo *id* del ítem republicado. Estaba pensando [buscarlo por nombre](https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLU/search?q=title), y luego filtrarlo por vendedor, pero... ¿Existe alguna otra manera directamente desde la *API* de *MercadoLibre*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto una respuesta que me envió el equipo de *MercadoLibre*:

Al ítem que queda finalizado en *MercadoLibre* lo llaman ítem padre, y la nueva republicación sería el hijo. No se tiene una forma de identificar a un hijo a partir de un padre. Sí se tiene una forma de hacerlo al revés, es decir, en el ítem hijo se tiene el campo *parent_item_id*, que sería el *ID* del padre que quedó finalizado.

Tienes que tener en cuenta que si se completó el campo *seller_custom_field* para agregar un *SKU* al ítem, el mismo campo se mantiene para el ítem hijo. Lo pueden utilizar de guía. Un recurso que puede ser útil:

```
https://api.mercadolibre.com/items?ids={item_id}&attributes=parent_item_id,id
```

Comment: Excelente, me funciono a la perfeccion.